# How to add a list as an element of a numpy n-D Matrix

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, append

I have been having lots for issues trying to find a way to put a list inside a numpy n-D Matrix. What I want is to have a numpy n-D matrix and all the elements inside that matrix should be lists. so that I can add/ append numbers into those lists.

```
 A = [X1,X2,X3]
     [Y1,Y2,Y3]
     [Z1,Z2,Z3]
```

ALL THE Xs,Ys AND Zs ARE LISTS.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a sample case?

Comment: I added a sample now

Comment: `np.vstack((X,Y,Z))` and `np.row_stack((X,Y,Z))` should solve it then.

Comment: how do I then append values to a specific position.

Comment: Think you should explain with an example on how and where you would like to append values.

Comment: if we consider that I want to add  a value to list x1, first I need to tell the position of that list inside the matrix which is (0,0) and then after that I need to add a value to that list lets say 21.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126724/discussion-between-d-wills-and-divakar).

Answer (score 1):

The general way to make such an array is to initial an object array, and fill it with your lists:

```
In [1706]: A=np.empty((3,3),dtype=object)
In [1707]: A
Out[1707]: 
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
In [1708]: A[0,1]=[1,2]
In [1709]: A[0,0]=[[1]]
In [1710]: A
Out[1710]: 
array([[[[1]], [1, 2], None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

If the lists vary in size you can construct such an array directly:

```
In [1711]: np.array([[1,2,3],[1]])
Out[1711]: array([[1, 2, 3], [1]], dtype=object)
```

but if they are all the same, you'll get a higher dimensional array

```
In [1712]: np.array([[1,2,3],[1,3,4]])
Out[1712]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 4]])
```

The subject of creating object arrays has come up quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Keep them as a list, and create a numpy object array

```
X1, X2, X3, Y1, Y2, Y3, Z1, Z2, Z3 = [], [], [], [] ,[] ,[] ,[] ,[] ,[]
my_array = np.array([[X1,X2,X3],[Y1,Y2,Y3],[Z1,Z2,Z3]])
#Suppose you want to append 690 to X1,
my_array[0,1].append(690)
```

Comment: using this appened method how do I append the value to a specific position. lets say I want to add 25,12,14 to position (0,0,1)

Comment: @D_Wills try now?

Comment: `my_array` is a `array([], shape=(3, 3, 0), dtype=float64)`.  That's not what we want.